# How To Change The Html of Products filtration sidebar in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have Used the function `dynamic_sidebar('sidebarId')` in the `sidebar.php` file.

and all the functionality of the sidebar is Working succsessfully

My Question is How To Change the Html of the sidebar widgets and add some classes in widget items To fit My Design ?

[image]
Thank You in advance

Comment: You have to customize that widget and from this link you can edit sidebar :https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the WooCommerce widgets via hooks. This might help you - https://www.skyverge.com/blog/overriddin-woocommerce-widgets/.